# About the exponential map $\exp: T_pM \to M$

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

This is somewhat pedantic, but when we talk about $\exp$ being a local diffeomorphism, what does it mean for $T_pM$ to carry an open set when it has no topology? Are we actually referring to the $TM$ instead?

Comment: There is a norm on $T_pM$ given by the Riemannian metric. (Then again, any norm would give an equivalent topology. And in fact any topological vector space topology in a finite dimensional space would be the same.)

Comment: to me $T_pM$ have the euclidean topology

Comment: Hang on just to recap, so if it has the Euclidean Topology what other content is it missing to be a (global) manifold? Paracompactness?

Comment: $TM$ is a manifold, and $T_pM$ sits inside it as a submanifold with some extra structure from the vector space aspect (and the inner product).  $\exp_p\colon T_pM\to M$ (or at least locally near $0$, since $M$ need not be complete) can then be described and make sense of.

Comment: No I m talking about $T_pM$, I know $TM$ is a manifold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ always has a canonical topology and analytic structure - the unique structure induced by any isomorphism with $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$.